# Search in .txt file in c++ only get's the first line

Tags: c++, file, search

I got some sort of room reservation program so i wanna search in .txt file so i can find the pre reserved rooms .

the Problem is:

The search function only reads the first line in the .txt file 
so when i enter a duplicated information it checks only the first line
can u help me out with it Thanks

```
int search(int search_num){    
string search= to_string(search_num);
int offset;
string line ;
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("booked.txt", ios::app);
ofstream booked ("booked.txt", ios ::app);
     if(myfile.is_open())
{
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile,line);
        if((offset=line.find(search,0))!=string :: npos)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 2;
            }
    }
    myfile.close();
}

else
    cout <<"Couldn't open" << endl;
```

}

Comment: That's because you put `return` after you've read the first line. Your program is only doing what you told it to.

Comment: It would be useful if you could indent your code in a systematic fashion so that it helps people who would like to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ending the execution of the function by returning a value in both cases of the if statement. Returning a value will end the execution of the function, so you always end after reading the first line. My guess is you want to move the `return 2;` to the very end of your function.

Note that this way you also always `return` without ever calling `myfile.close()` which might cause problems elsewhere. While I don't understand the meaning of your return values 1 and 2, I suggest this:

```
int search(int search_num){    
 string search= to_string(search_num);
 int offset;
 string line ;
 ifstream myfile;
 myfile.open("booked.txt", ios::app);
 int return_value = 2;
 ofstream booked ("booked.txt", ios ::app);
 if(myfile.is_open()) {
    while(!myfile.eof()) {
        getline(myfile,line);
        if((offset=line.find(search,0))!=string :: npos) {
            return_value = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
 } else {
    cout <<"Couldn't open" << endl;
 }
 return return_value;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, except the point about `myfile.close()`. The ofstream destructor will close the file however the function is exited. Closing the file explicitly is actually unnecessary (although not wrong).

Comment: Sir thanks very much , u are the man :) 
but pls if u can help me with some thing else how can i delete a specific value in the . txt file ?

Comment: @user3024817 Deletion from files is not possible. All you can do is copy the file but miss out the part you want to delete.

Comment: @john but how can i miss the part i want to delete ?? 
sorry but am kinda of beginner first i copy the file to a new one then recopy to the original file without the part i wanna to delete right ?

Comment: @BishoyM, my advice would be loading in the text file, all its data, into some structures capable of storing the data (like classes or structs), changing these variables in your code, and then saving everything back to the txt file. This is a complex topic not only worthy of a seperate question, but also some research on your side. Start with a simple program loading an `int` from a file into an `int` variable, changing and saving it to a txt file. Then expand.

Comment: @BishoyM Right, that's how you do it. jens is right too, you should write one function to load the file into some data structure, another function to write the data structure to a file, and then all you have to do is delete whatever it is from your data structure. This is good program design.